# Threading with python trouble (dht22)

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, raspberry-pi, sensors

Dealing with a smart garden setup. I am doing threading with three different functions so that if triggered I can run the lamp/pump/fan for a predetermined time. While threading with lamp and pump there is no problem. But when attempting to thread with Dht22 the program will work for a while and then throw an error of "argument must be an int, or be format of file.no()" I think the problem is due to the array format, but I don't know how to read just the temperature from the dht22 or to make the thread work with the array. Thanks for the help

Here is my code:

```
import time
import datetime
import grovepi
import threading


# Pin-modes

dht_sensor = 4                  
light_sensor = 0           
moisture_sensor = 1         

pump = 3        ######
lamp = 7        ######       
fan = 8         ######

grovepi.pinMode(dht_sensor, "INPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(light_sensor, "INPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(moisture_sensor, "INPUT")

grovepi.pinMode(pump, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(lamp, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(fan, "OUTPUT")

# Threshold values

temp_crit_val = 90       
light_crit_val = 10
moisture_crit_val = 60

def lamp_auto():
    while True:
         readTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

        if(11 < int(readTime) < 19) or (31 < int(readTime) < 39) or (51 < int(readTime) < 59):
             actualTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
             light = grovepi.analogRead(light_sensor)
             light = 100 * light / 1023
             print("Light = ",light)
             if ((actualTime > "07:03")and(actualTime < "18:34")): #sunrise and sunset
                 if light <= light_crit_val:
                     grovepi.digitalWrite(lamp, 1)
            else:
                grovepi.digitalWrite(lamp, 0)
        else:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(lamp,0)

        time.sleep(5)


def pump_auto():     
    while True:
         readTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

         if(11 < int(readTime) < 19) or (31 < int(readTime) < 39) or (51 < int(readTime) < 59):
             soil_moisture = grovepi.analogRead(moisture_sensor)
             soil_moisture = 100 - (100 * soil_moisture / 1023)
             print("Soil Moisture = ",soil_moisture)

             if soil_moisture <= moisture_crit_val:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(pump, 1)
        else:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(pump, 0)

    time.sleep(5)


def fan_auto():
     readTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

     if(11 < int(readTime) < 19) or (31 < int(readTime) < 39) or (51 < int(readTime) < 59):
         [temp,hum] = grovepi.dht(dht_sensor,1)
         temp = temp*9/5+32
         if all ([temp,hum]):
             print('temperature={} humidity={}'.format(temp,hum)
             if temp >= temp_crit_val:
                 grovepi.digitalWrite(fan, 1)
                time.sleep(50)
             else:
                 grovepi.digitalWrite(fan, 0)
      time.sleep(5)


x = threading.Thread(target=lamp_auto)
x.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
y =  threading.Thread(target=pump_auto)
y.start()

while True:
    fan_auto()
```

Error:
      '''
      I/O operation on a closed file
      argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method
      '''

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: better copy full error instead of trying `"error look like this"`

Comment: first you should check what you get from sensor - at least use `print()` to see it. And then you can try to resolve problem. Maybe you will have to only check if data is not `None`. OR maybe you will have to put code in `try/except` to catch error and skip data.

Comment: But that's the thing, python doesn't throw a traceback error. It just prints "I/O operation on a closed file argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method" infinite times on the shell.

Comment: Can you get this to happen by just running the DHT code without any multithreading?

Comment: If I comment out the threading, the dht22 sensor and the def fan_auto(): work just fine. Accurate readings and what not. So the issue lies within the threading somewhere

Comment: @Lucas so if you run your above code exactly with only `x.start()` and `y.start()` commented out, you don't see the same problem? Sounds to me like non thread safe bus communications.. one of the threads is occupying the bus (i2c) when another tries to access it.

Comment: So I made fan_auto into its own thread. I also edited the temperature to be "temperature = int(temperature*9/5+32)" and when I run it like that I do get a traceback error:   '''Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/operation.py", line 78, in fan_auto
    temperature = int(temperature*9/5+32)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer'''

Comment: sorry i don't know how to paste the error as code. I'm new here

Comment: The above error is unrelated. DHT cannot produce readings very quickly and will return `NaN` if no reading is available. `NaN` is a proper float value, but cannot be converted to an int. you should check if the value returned is Nan before proceeding with computation. It effectively means the sensor isn't ready to return a value yet.

Comment: Hmm yes okay. I think your right with the non thread safe bus communications. I'll have to do some research and try to remedy that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a bit like the hardware interface is not liking the threading. This could definitely be debugged and fixed, but this application does not scream multi-threading to me. A simple task queue should do the trick:

```
import time
import datetime
import grovepi


# Pin-modes

dht_sensor = 4                  
light_sensor = 0           
moisture_sensor = 1         

pump = 3        ######
lamp = 7        ######       
fan = 8         ######

grovepi.pinMode(dht_sensor, "INPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(light_sensor, "INPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(moisture_sensor, "INPUT")

grovepi.pinMode(pump, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(lamp, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(fan, "OUTPUT")

# Threshold values

temp_crit_val = 90       
light_crit_val = 10
moisture_crit_val = 60

def lamp_auto():
    readTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

    if(11 < int(readTime) < 19) or (31 < int(readTime) < 39) or (51 < int(readTime) < 59):
        actualTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        light = grovepi.analogRead(light_sensor)
        light = 100 * light / 1023
        print("Light = ",light)
        if ((actualTime > "07:03")and(actualTime < "18:34")): #sunrise and sunset
            if light <= light_crit_val:
                grovepi.digitalWrite(lamp, 1)
        else:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(lamp, 0)
    else:
        grovepi.digitalWrite(lamp,0)

    return time.time() + 5 #return next scheduled time to execute


def pump_auto():
     readTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

     if(11 < int(readTime) < 19) or (31 < int(readTime) < 39) or (51 < int(readTime) < 59):
         soil_moisture = grovepi.analogRead(moisture_sensor)
         soil_moisture = 100 - (100 * soil_moisture / 1023)
         print("Soil Moisture = ",soil_moisture)

         if soil_moisture <= moisture_crit_val:
             grovepi.digitalWrite(pump, 1)
     else:
         grovepi.digitalWrite(pump, 0)

     return time.time() + 5 #return next scheduled time to execute


def fan_auto():
     readTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")

     if(11 < int(readTime) < 19) or (31 < int(readTime) < 39) or (51 < int(readTime) < 59):
         [temp,hum] = grovepi.dht(dht_sensor,1)
         temp = temp*9/5+32
         if all ([temp,hum]):
             print('temperature={} humidity={}'.format(temp,hum))
             if temp >= temp_crit_val:
                 grovepi.digitalWrite(fan, 1)
                 return time.time() + 50 #return next scheduled time to execute
             else:
                 grovepi.digitalWrite(fan, 0)
     return time.time() + 5 #return next scheduled time to execute



#using collections.deque might be faster or more efficient here, but it wouldn't be noticible.
task_queue = [(0, lamp_auto), #schedule the three services to start right away
              (0, pump_auto),
              (0, fan_auto)]

while len(task_queue) > 0: #while there are remaining tasks
    t, func = task_queue.pop(0) #get next task
    wait_time = t - time.time()
    if wait_time > 0:
        time.sleep(wait_time)
    t_next = func()
    #insert (t_next, func) into queue, such that the queue remains sorted
    for i in range(len(task_queue)):
        if t_next < task_queue[i][0]:
            task_queue.insert(i, (t_next, func))
            break
    else:
        task_queue.append((t_next, func))
```

Comment: I don't have the same hardware to be able to test this, but I pretty much left the code alone aside from moving all the `time.sleep` calls to the task handling loop.

Comment: Ok I'll try and implement this. Thanks!

Comment: your code seems to be doing the functionality needed for my project! Thanks so much for your help! I'll have to really read your code so I can fully understand it and learn from it. I tried to upvote you but stackoverflow says I'm not a high enough level haha

Comment: If this answer was able to solve your problem, you should be able to mark it as the accepted answer (check mark below up/down vote buttons). User reputation is used to initially limit privileges to cut down on bot accounts, and prevent user spam so don't worry about it.